# SQL : Select record by passing a date within the range

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have table Structure like this

```
id   from                    to
1    2014-02-01 00:00:00     2014-02-28 00:00:00 
2    2014-01-01 00:00:00     2014-01-30 00:00:00 
3    2014-03-01 00:00:00     2014-03-30 00:00:00
```

and There is no date range overlapping in this

I'm trying to select record by passing a date which lie within the range

eg. passing date `'2014-01-16'` should return the record with `id=2` as it falls within the range of the dates in this row, please guide me to solve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @OlafDietsche sorry abt my typo

Comment: 2014-02-30 ? In which country do you live? :-) Seriously, is this really a datetime field?

Comment: @Steve its just test data i have added, i have corrected my mistake

Comment: But if you are able to insert this value then the TO field is not a datetime type. Right?

Comment: @Steve actual format is like this `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`

Comment: @Steve: this is best date format, also known as [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). It is easiest to parse, and always sorts well

Comment: @mvp I don't know MySql very well, but the original test data contains 2014-02-30 as you can see from the history of this question. That's the reason of my comment. Does MySql allow an invalid date to be stored in a datetime column?

Comment: @Steve: every database and language out there supports ISO 8601 which is an international standard, and MySQL is not an exception. In that sense, this date is valid. In old versions MySQL allowed to store invalid dates like Feb 31st, but I think it has improved recently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE '2014-01-16' BETWEEN `from` AND `to`
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bef51/1)**

Comment: You're welcome! Be sure to add indexes for your `from` and `to` columns - it will make it work fast for large tables

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE from <= '2014-01-16' AND to >= '2014-01-16'
```